# Getting wrong clientHeight of a ref inside componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

so when i try to get the clientheight of the image div im getting the wrong value.Instead if i set a height to imgdiv im getting that value.

**React:**

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.imgref = React.createRef();
      }

    componentDidMount(){
   
        console.log(this.centerref.current.clientHeight);
    
    }
    render(){
      return (
      <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="imgdiv" ref={this.imgref}><img src="" } /></div>
    </div>
    );
    }
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex: 1;
        height: 100%;
        }
        .imgdiv{
        flex: 0 0 auto;
        }
       .imgdiv img{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

Comment: Please remember to look at your post, and fix markup problems. Your code definitely needs an indentation and newline edit. Also note that your code has syntax errors: at the very least there's a rogue `}` in there, so: remember to _verify_ that the code you show is real code. Even if it's reduced code.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Sorry for the wrong format.From next time i will keep this in mind.Someone has edited it for me now.Thank you

Comment: use should use `this.imgref` in `componentDidMount`. also your `imgdiv` has no height property. its height will be calculated automatically based on the content. what do you mean by you are getting the wrong value?

Comment: @Naresh sorry for the typo im using this.imgref in my code and the height im getting is 24px but the image size is 171px

Comment: @SandeepKollabathula note that your post is _still_ poorly formatted. The edit did not fix that, so please still take the time to clean up your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your image is taking some time to render that's why you are not getting the actual image size but the size of the container.

You can update your image tag like this

```
<img
   src=""
   alt="hello"
   onLoad={this.onImageLoad}
 />
```

and create a `onImageLoad` handler

```
  onImageLoad = () => {
    console.log(this.imgref.current.clientHeight); // actual image size
  };
```

check [this codesand box](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-violet-qdcke)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)?

```js
const rect = this.centerref.current.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(rect.height);
```

Also just might be that your image needs to load before you can get the correct height. For a quick and dirty way to see if that is it, set a long timeout around the log and see if it shows the correct height then. If thats the problem, add some loading logic like this:

```js
const img = new Image();
img.src = 'path/to/img.jpg';
img.onload = () => {
    console.log(img.height);
}
```